# Argument of the utility "file" in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, file, pipe, utility

Okay so what I am trying to do, there is an utility called "file" in bash and I want to pass it all files in current directory and in all subdirectories as an argument. Best thing would be, if I could pass it list of files from "find"

```
find -type f | file * -b
```

but the "file" doesnt work like that, it needs an argument like this

```
file /argument/ -b
```

I was also trying to use some regex, but it doesnt work either.

Comment: Actually, the `-b` should go **before** the names. See [POSIX utility syntax guidelines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) number 9: "All options should precede operands on the command line".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could try

```
find . -type f -exec file -b {} +
```

Comment: No need for the backslash before the `+`; that's only needed for the `;` form.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy ah yes. My fingers has a bad habit. :) thanx.

Answer (score 1):

something like this should work

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 file -b
```

Here, first `find` finds the files of interest, makes sure that their names are delimited with null byte and passes this list to `xargs` which then calls `file` on chunks of size 1, i.e., on each file separately...

But in principle, `file` can handle multiple input arguments at once so one might increase the size of the chunks in order to decrease the total number of executions of this utility...

Also, you might force `file` to read its input from standard input like so:

```
find . -type f | file -f- -b
```

The `-f` option specifies the file from which `file` should load the files to be identified, `-` then requests to use standard input.

Comment: `-print0 | xargs -0` is, in more recent implementations of `find`, better replaced with `-exec ... {} +`-- which, like `xargs`, groups arguments into as few invocations as possible, but does so without requiring non-POSIX extensions. (`find -exec ... {} +` has been POSIX-specified since 2006 or so, whereas `xargs -0` is still not part of the standard).

Comment: ...correcting myself: That was POSIX Issue 6, so `-exec ... {} +` has been valid since 2004.